# django functional testing with selenium database creation

Tags: django, selenium

I am following the [TddjangoTutorial](http://www.tdd-django-tutorial.com/tutorial/2/). My question is that when I visit 
localhost:8000/admin/polls/poll to create a new poll, it complains that the poll table is not there. This is fixed by running the syncdb command, which creates the table. But when I ran selenium test before running the command, it worked fine. The test opens localhost:8081/admin/polls/poll. It showed the page to add a new poll. Does the functional test automatically create this table?

Code for functional test:

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from userFactory import UserFactory

class PollsTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)
        self.user = UserFactory.create()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_can_create_new_poll_via_admin_site(self):
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url+'/admin/')
        body = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
        self.assertIn('Django administration', body.text)

        username_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('username')
        username_field.send_keys(self.user.username)

        password_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('password')
        password_field.send_keys('adm1n')
        password_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        body = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')

        self.assertIn('Site administration', body.text)
        polls_links = self.browser.find_elements_by_link_text('Polls')
        self.assertEqual(len(polls_links), 2)
        polls_links[1].click()

        #the user is taken to the polls listing page, which shows no polls yet
        body = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
        self.assertIn('0 polls', body.text)

        # the user clicks on add to add a new poll
        new_poll_link = self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('Add poll')
        new_poll_link.click()

        body = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
        self.assertIn('Question:', body.text)
        self.assertIn('Date published:', body.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the original doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

> Tests that require a database (namely, model tests) will not use your “real” (production) database. Separate, blank databases are created for the tests.
>
> Regardless of whether the tests pass or fail, the test databases are destroyed when all the tests have been executed.